# Android Interface not getting initialised - callback in android

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an issue in callback interface initialization.

I have to pass the push notification data to my MainActivity (HomeActivity).

So, I have a listener (interface object) as below :

```
    class FirebaseMessageReceiver : FirebaseMessagingService() {
...
    lateinit var pushNotificationArrivedListener:PushNotificationListener
...

}
```

Inside the method :

```
 override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {

if (this::pushNotificationArrivedListener.isInitialized && pushNotificationArrivedListener != null) {
            pushNotificationArrivedListener.onPushNotificationArrived(firmwareObj)
        }

}
```

Where,
In same class the interface is created as below :

```
interface PushNotificationListener {
    fun onPushNotificationArrived(firmwareObj:FirmwarePushNotification)
}
```

Overriding it in **HomeActivity** as below :

```
override fun onPushNotificationArrived(firmwareObj: FirmwarePushNotification) {
        Log.e("&&&&& ","&&&&& onPushNotificationArrived")
        
    }
```

Implementing and Initiating it as below in HomeActivity :

```
class HomeActivity : AppActivity(),FirebaseMessageReceiver.PushNotificationListener {
```

and inside onCreate() initializing the interface as below :

```
firebaseMessageReceiver.initializePushNotificationListener(this)
```

WHERE,

```
firebaseMessageReceiver is initialized in App.kt class as below :

        var firebaseMessageReceiver: FirebaseMessageReceiver = FirebaseMessageReceiver()
```

Everything is looks correct,
But listener is not getting initialized.. i.e. below if condition is not satisfying :

```
 if (this::pushNotificationArrivedListener.isInitialized && pushNotificationArrivedListener != null) {
```

What might be the issue?

**EDIT**
Below is the method also inside class :

```
fun initializePushNotificationListener(pushNotificationArrivedListener: PushNotificationListener) {
    this.pushNotificationArrivedListener = pushNotificationArrivedListener
}
```

Comment: Is your `onMessageReceived` even triggered?

Comment: Yes, Its triggred and I am also getting exception if not checking that Its null or not.

Comment: We don't need to initialize FirebaseMessageReceiver class as it will be initialized by the app that's why it gives null every time with your listener.

Comment: @MohitDholakia thanks. Do you have any idea that How can we initialize listener inside FirebaseMessageReceiver class ? means how to call method initializePushNotificationListener() in activity.?

Comment: @Jaimin As far as I know, we can't get that object of FirebaseMessageReceiver class so to pass data from FCM class to activity you should use RXBus or LocalBroadCastManager.

Comment: You can't implement listeners like that from `FirebaseMessagingService()` since that service is not initialised by your app. Few ways to achieve that is by either using local broadcast managers, or by implement pending intent to receive intent data into activity or else storing data into database and then receiving it on activity by db.